# Chrome extension - collect HTMLcollection from file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a in house chrome extension which collects data from a webpage (broke links etc for SEO) but i'm having issues. My original script injected the js onpage which was great as it had a box and collected what was needed, the only issue was it wasn't a Popup box so it didn't close correctly etc. I now have a script which on load pulls all dom data and a script which display and manipulates the data. The only issue I have is collecting the data from the file.

Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.2.4",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "",
  "homepage_url": "",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js", 
      "Returndocdata.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": ""
  },
  "icons": { "16": "icon16.png" },
  "permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "tabs"
  ],
   "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "js": ["Returndocdata.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab, info) {

    chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: 'Returndocdata.js'}); 

});

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab, info) {

    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: "inject.html"})

});
```

inject.html

```
<div id = "ContactDetails">
    <input type="text" name="lname">
</div>

<script src="inject.js"></script>
```

Returndocdata.js

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
console.log(all);
```

inject.js

this is the file that needs the returndocdata.js data, i need a way to grab that data and pull it into this keeping the formatting (the htmlcollection)

This works if I include the script in the header but due to it not being ran on the web page itself it only returns data from the popup extension.

It's most likely a small thing

Ta

Comment: You can't have both the popup page AND onClicked. Choose one. Also, the browserAction popup is *not injected* anywhere. It's an entirely separate page displayed in a separate window with its own separate URL like chrome-extension://extensionID/popup-file-name.html. It means to get something from the web page you need a content script which is injected indeed alongside the web page.

Comment: Yes, I know. My issue is to get the data

Comment: It works when I inject it but it didn't work as a popup

Comment: I use extensions which have data collected from HTML and popup.